# How to ignore hidden cells when pulling data from one workbook to another

Tags: excel

I am familiar with Excel's ability to pull data from one workbook to another. For example, if I have a workbook, `workbook-1.xlsx`, I can pull data from cell `A8` of `workbook-1.xlsx` to cell A1 of `workbook-2.xlsx`, using the formula:

```
='C:\users\username\documents\[workbook-1.xlsx]Sheet1'!A8
```

If I drag the cursor in the corner of the box down, it will reproduce this result, and pull data from cells `A9`, `A10`, and so on, into cells `A2`, `A3`, and so on. Now supposing in my workbook, `workbook-1.xlsx`, I have a range of cells from `A8` to `A15`, where some cells are hidden. I would like to pull data from only those cells which are visible.

Assuming all the cells are visible we obtain the following map:

```
A8  --> A1
A9  --> A2
A10 --> A3
A11 --> A4
A12 --> A5
A13 --> A6
A14 --> A7
A15 --> A8
```

However, supposing cells `A10` and `A11` are hidden, how do I obtain the following map?

```
A8  --> A1
A9  --> A2
A12 --> A3
A13 --> A4
A14 --> A5
A15 --> A6
```

Effectively, I want hidden cells to be simply ignored. Ideally then, I'm looking for a function of the form:

```
=IF('[workbook-1.xlsx]Sheet1'!A8_is_visible, '[workbook-1.xlsx]Sheet1'!A8, skip)
```

Is there a way to implement this in Excel 2010? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you hiding the cells with filter or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Using Formula you can do:
If you are using Filter to hide some cells you can create a new column near your Data and write in B8 for example before hiding Data:

```
=SUBTOTAL(103,$A$8:$A8)
```

and drag it down, when you apply the filter it will write a sequential number for visible rows only
Change your formula to:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('C:\users\username\documents\[workbook-1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$8:$A$15,MATCH(ROW()-1,'C:\users\username\documents\[workbook-1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$8:$A$15,0)),"")
```

and drag it down
Or you can use VBA